# Calculate a sum on from a derivative column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Group by on from a derivative column

**Context**

Following this table,

[image: email recipient table]

Our goal is to compute a value from the status field name recipient_score, group on other columns and sum.
Following this rule,

```
Following this rule, 

   TO => 3
   BCC => 2
   FROM => 5
```

And group is_read and sum.
That way we could have

```
EmailRecipient.with_score.group(:is_read).sum('recipient.score')

returning

{
  true:  7, #(To : 3) + Bcc (2 *2 ) #
  false: 5  #(From)
}
```

I tried to create a class method with score

```
class EmailRecipient < ApplicationRecord

  def self.with_score
    select("#{table_name}.* as email_recipient", 
      "CASE 
        WHEN #{table_name}.status = 'TO' THEN '3' 
        WHEN #{table_name}.status = 'BCC' THEN '2'
        WHEN #{table_name}.status = 'FROM' THEN '5' 
        ELSE '1' 
      END as recipient_score
      ")
  end
end
```

But the result is not really conclusive.

```
[3] pry(main)> EmailRecipient.with_score.group(:is_read).sum('recipient_score')
   (9.4ms)  SELECT SUM(recipient_score) AS sum_recipient_score, "email_recipients"."is_read" AS email_recipients_is_read FROM "email_recipients" GROUP BY "email_recipients"."is_read"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "recipient_score" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(recipient_score) AS sum_recipient_score, "email_r...
                   ^
: SELECT SUM(recipient_score) AS sum_recipient_score, "email_recipients"."is_read" AS email_recipients_is_read FROM "email_recipients" GROUP BY "email_recipients"."is_read"
from /Users/edouardetancelin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:600:in `async_exec'
Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "recipient_score" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(recipient_score) AS sum_recipient_score, "email_r...
```

Does anyone have any idea in order to perform that ?

Comment: I think the issue here is that `.sum` overrides the select statement of the scope. IMHO ActiveRecord::Calculations is pretty useless except for the most trivial of tasks as it does not add an aggregate to the query. It nukes the whole query and just returns an aggregate. In this case you might want to use `EmailRecipient.connection.execute` to do a "raw" query.

Comment: Also can you add an example of what the desired output is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def self.calc_score 
  subquery = select(
                "*",
                "CASE status
                  WHEN 'TO'   THEN 3 
                  WHEN 'BCC'  THEN 2
                  WHEN 'FROM' THEN 5
                  ELSE 1
                END AS score"
              )
  select('*').from(subquery, :sub).group(:is_read).sum(:score)
end
```

```
=> EmailRecipient.calc_score
=> {"FALSE"=>5, "TRUE"=>7}
```